# Python imported module dependency

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have file main.py :

```
import math
import mymodule.py
print(math.ceil(5/3))
```

and then mymodule.py :

```
print(math.ceil(10/3))
```

mymodule.py gives an error that math is not defined, even though its parent module has it imported.

Considering **both** `main.py` and `mymodule.py` need to use the `math` lib, do I need to import it twice? It just seems non-optimal. What's the most pythonic way to solve this issue?

I know it's a dumb example, but I'm trying to fragment a code I made into several modules for organization, and this issue appeared multiple times in several levels

Comment: just import it again

Comment: The most Pythonic - and in fact the only - way is to import it in both files. That's how Python works.

Comment: @ryugie In this example, yes, but in reality I broke down a file into several modules and this issue repeated many times at several levels

Comment: It will depend upon if you are importing consistently. For e.g. `import math` vs `from math import *` or just importing specific methods from `math`. If your import and application is consistent it should not cause issue,

Comment: Re-imports are cheap. You shouldn't think of importing the same module twice as a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mymodule.py` is parent for `main.py` since you are importing `mymodule` within `main`.
You need to import `math` within `mymodule` so that it gets inherited in `main`.
Then there won't be a need to import within `main`.

mymodule.py

```
import math
```

main.py

```
import  mymodule
print mymodule.math.pow(10,2)
```

Result:

```
>>> 
100.0
>>>
```

Comment: Hmm. I thought `main.py` was the parent, so I can import in `mymodule.py `only?

Comment: It depends which module you are importing to where. See my example above.

Comment: you really don't need to do `from mymodule import *` .  That's overkill.  You can just `import mymodule` unless you want to call a specific function or class (e.g. `from mymodule import aFunc`)

Comment: I made it more modular and less cluttering of namespace. Although, my intention was to show simple example that demonstrates solution.

Comment: user, no doubt, but I'm assuming this is just a concept sketch.  I don't assume anyone would have a separate file just to `import math`.

Answer (score 1):

This is really very basic.  If you have something in a separate file, like mymodule.py, then you can import that function in any python file easily in the same directory.

two files:

mymodule.py:

```
import math

def aFunc():
    return math.ceil(10/3)


# We could also just use this file as a standalone
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(aFunc())
```

main.py:

```
import mymodule

print(mymodule.aFunc())
```

You could also specifically call out the function you want to import.

main.py (alternative):

```
from mymodule import aFunc

print(aFunc())
```